# DAX calculate hierarchy ratio when columns from two tables

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have created a matrix table with three levels, namely style, channel, and size, to calculate the quantity and corresponding percentage of each level in the "style_selling_df" table. To give a specific sorting to the size level, I created another table "custom_sortby", made a relationship with the "style_selling_df" table using the size column, and then activated the relationship. While creating the matrix table, I used the size column from the "custom_sortby" table. Pleaes see DAX below:

```
var stylesubtotal = calculate(sum(Style_selling_df[quantity]), allselected(Style_selling_df[style]));
var channelsubtotal = calculate(sum(Style_selling_df[quantity]), allselected(Style_selling_df[channelgrouping]));
var sizesubtotal = calculate(sum(Style_selling_df[quantity]), allselected(Style_selling_df[size]));
return if(
  Isinscope(Style_selling_df[size]),
  divide(sum(Style_selling_df[quantity]), sizesubtotal),
  if(
    isinscope(Style_selling_df[channelgrouping]),
    divide(sum(Style_selling_df[quantity]), channelsubtotal),
    if(
      isinscope(Style_selling_df[style]),
      divide(sum(Style_selling_df[quantity]), stylesubtotal),
      divide(sum(Style_selling_df[quantity]), channelsubtotal)
    )
  )
);
```

[Please see screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jV5dl.png)

However, the percentages obtained are correct for all levels except for the size level. How can I fix this

Comment: Your question is well-written but the code is hard to follow.  Could you pretty-print the code or somehow style the code so that it can be more easily followed?  I suggest using a code block.

Comment: Please see the updated code. Appreciated.